# Leveraging Measurement Protocol to connect Google Analytics to CRM

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

I've fond this reference online about using the measurement protocol to capture user data from your CRM and appending it to the information that Google Analytics also captures, to get a holistic snapshot of your customer. https://www.upbuild.io/blog/crm-data-google-analytics-measurement-protocol/#comments

My questions is: Is the measurement protocol the right tool to match records in Hubspot to records in Google Analytics?

Can I use it to send Hubspot Client ID/ Properties to Google Analytics at the client level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with the same principle described in the comment of your link.